# Не находит кнопку R.id.home из ActionBar. Нужно ли ее заранее определять?

Tags: java, android, actionbar, android-toolbar

Отображаю кнопку "назад" в ActionBar

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Пытаюсь обработать нажатие, а не срабатывает.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.home) {
......
return true;
}
```

Может где-то нужно заранее определить кнопке назад @+id/home?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`android.R.id.home` вместо `R.id.home`